# Golang Build Constraints Random

Tags: build, compilation, go

I have two go files with different build constraints in the header.

constants_production.go:

```
// +build production,!staging

package main

const (
  URL               = "production"
)
```

constants_staging.go:

```
// +build staging,!production

package main

const (
  URL               = "staging"
)
```

main.go:

```
package main

func main() {
  fmt.Println(URL)
}
```

When I do a `go install -tags "staging"`, sometimes, it prints `production`; Sometimes, it prints `staging`. Similarly, when I do `go install -tags "production"`,...

How do I get a consistent output on every build?  How do I make it print staging when I specify staging as a build flag? How do I make it print production when I specify production as a build flag? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`go build` and `go install` will not rebuild the package (binary) if it looks like nothing has changed -- and it's not sensitive to changes in command-line build tags.

One way to see this is to add `-v` to print the packages as they are built:

```
$ go install -v -tags "staging"
my/server
$ go install -v -tags "production"
(no output)
```

You can force a rebuild by adding the `-a` flag, which tends to be overkill:

```
$ go install -a -v -tags "production"
my/server
```

...or by touching a server source file before the build:

```
$ touch main.go
$ go install -a -tags "staging"
```

...or manually remove the binary before the build:

```
$ rm .../bin/server
$ go install -a -tags "production"
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. The binaries are not being rebuilt like you said. Thanks.