# Negative build tags not working as expected

Tags: go

I have 3 files. One `main` and two additional ones `normal` `gokrazy` which ~are~ should be alternatively be built depending on build constraint. Both update a global var from `main` during `init()`. `normal` is

```
// +build !gokrazy

package main

import "fmt"

func init() {
    foo = "normal"
    fmt.Println("init:", foo)
}
```

the other `gokrazy` is:

```
// +build gokrazy

package main

import "fmt"

func init() {
    foo = "gokrazy"
    fmt.Println("init:", foo)
}
```

`go vet *.go` is happy. When I run `go run *.go` I see that **BOTH** init functions are called:

```
init: gokrazy
init: normal
```

I expected only one to be called. `go list` confirms that the expected files are selected, however I still see both init functions. [Golang Build Constraints Random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346261/golang-build-constraints-random) explains that a forced compile might be necessary, however that does not change the result:

```
❯ go list -f '{{.GoFiles}}' -tags=gokrazy -a && go run -tags=gokrazy -a *.go
[gokrazy.go main.go]
init: gokrazy
init: normal
```

Why does the negative `!gokrazy` build tag not take effect?

Comment: Never use go run with filename arguments! Actually never use go run! **Never**! Especially not with **build** tags: Build tags are for build as you could tell by their name. `go run` simply ignores build tags (and this is the only sensible use case for go run: Execute a helper script excluded from the build). Also `go vet *.go` is wrong too: The go tool works on packages and not on files. Use  go vet and go build and drop go run from your toolset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go does actually run all the files if you use `go run *.go`. Instead use:

```sh
go run .
```

---

For example if you have a test file (`main_test.go`) in the folder and use `go run *.go`, it will complain:

> go run: cannot run *_test.go files (main_test.go)

Answer (score 1):

Build tags modify what is built (as the name implies).

Build tags are basically ignored for `go run` which you should not use anyway (it is just too complicated to get it right except `go run .`)

Use `go build`.